# Java 2D Array: Go through groups of entries and sum their values

Tags: java, arrays, sum

Let's say that there exists a 2D Java array *(4x6 for representation purposes)* filled with numbers ranging from 1 to 9 in a random order.

What if one wanted to calculate the **individual sum of all groups of numbers in that array**?

*Simple illustration:*
[image: 4x6 array containing six 2x2 arrays filled with random numbers]

In this particular case:

1. Sum of the blue area
2. Sum of the violet area
3. Sum of the red area
4. Sum of the yellow area
5. ...

The following code works for any array, but only if each entry is precisely 1x1 big which is useless in this case (and any other case), as it simply goes through all entries.

```
for (int a = 0; a < x; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < y; b++) {
        sum = array[a][b];
    }
}
```

How would you make it go through groups of entries and then sum all values located in an individual group?

Comment: Add a conditional statement in your loop to ignore others groups, like if we want to get members of yellow square: `if (a>2) continue ` ...

Answer (score 0):

`startx`, `starty`, `endx`, `endy` is the answer to that. You will iterate from `start` to `end`. This does require you to know (or be able to calculate) those variables. If not please clarify the exact structure.

If your array is declared like:

```
int[][] matrix = new int [4][6];
```

A rough example:

```
public int sumOfSubMatrix (int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = startx; x <= endx; x++) {
        for (int y = starty; y <= endy; y++) {
            sum += matrix[x][y];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

You simply add every "cell" to the sum variable.

Now, this is not possible if the "colors" were spread out, even one cell being off, then the algorithm has to something of them, like their position. If the structure is 100% chaotic then your best option is brute force with `if-guard`s.